# Handle click outside of React component and how to add animation to it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have read a lot of similar articles like the following items:

1. [Detect click outside the react component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553158/detect-click-outside-react-component)
2. [Click outside of clickable components in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39538696/click-outside-of-clickable-components-in-react)
3. etc.

And I have read many of their answers, but it doesn't help me to solve my problem.

I have a `navbar` component, which has a bars icon on it. whenever a user clicks on it, it should show the `sidebar` component and in case the user clicks outside the `sidebar` component, it should be on hidden state (like first).

Here is what I have implemented:

navbar.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Icon} from 'antd';

import Sidebar from '../sidebar/sidebar.js';
import '../../css/navbar.css';

class Navbar extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sidebarVisible: false
        }
        this.sidebarShow = this.sidebarShow.bind(this);
        this.sidebarHide = this.sidebarHide.bind(this);
    }

    sidebarShow(){
        this.setState({
            sidebarVisible: true
        })
        document.addEventListener('click', this.sidebarHide);
    }

    sidebarHide(){
        this.setState({
            sidebarVisible: false
        })

        document.removeEventListener('click', this.sidebarHide)
    }

    render (){
        return (
            <div className="nav-container">

                <div className="bar" onClick={() => this.sidebarShow()} >
                    <Icon type="bars"/>
                </div>

                <div className="nav-logo">
                    خفت کتاب
                </div>

                {this.state.sidebarVisible ? <Sidebar/> : null}

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Navbar
```

sidebar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Icon} from 'antd';

import '../../css/sidebar.css'

class Sidebar extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="sidebar">
                <div className="sidebar-user">
                    <div className="sidebar-profile">
                        <img src={require('../../images/personal.jpg')}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="sidebar-welcome">
                        مصطفی قدیمی
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="sidebar-active sidebar-elements">
                    <div className="sidebar-icon">
                        <Icon type="home" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="sidebar-title">
                        خانه
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="sidebar-elements">
                    <div className="sidebar-icon">
                        <Icon type="book" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="sidebar-title">
                        ثبت کتاب
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="sidebar-elements">
                    <div className="sidebar-icon">
                        <Icon type="info-circle" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="sidebar-title">
                        درباره ما
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="sidebar-elements">
                    <div className="sidebar-icon">
                        <Icon type="mail" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="sidebar-title">
                        تماس با ما
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

sidebar.css

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #001529;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: white;
    animation-name: 'sidebar';
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}

.sidebar > div {
    padding: 10px;
}


.sidebar-elements {
    background-color: #334454;
    opacity: 0.4;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 40px auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.sidebar-elements:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-duration: .5s;
}

.sidebar-icon {
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
}

.sidebar-profile {
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #334454;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar-profile > img {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.sidebar-welcome {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
}

.sidebar-active {
    background-color: #1890ff;
    opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes sidebar {
    from {transform: translateX(250px);}
    to {transform: translateX(0);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes sidebar { 
    from {transform: translateX(250px);}
    to {transform: translateX(0);}
}
```

> The main problem of this implementation is whenever the user clicks on click on `sidebar` component, it becomes invisible. How to prevent it from hiding?
>    **Note:** Is there any way to add animation when the user click on outside of the component?

Comment: it's normal when you show the sidebar you subscribe to event document click document.addEventListener('click', this.sidebarHide).  In your sidebar component you add and event click with event stop propagation

Comment: Apart from handling the close event, the main issue seems to be mounting/unmounting the `<Sidebar>` component. Notice the `this.state.sidebarVisible ? <Sidebar/> : null` in `navbar.js` in which the Sidebar is unmounted/removed from the DOM immediately. I'd rather keep the `<Sidebar>` and play with its HTML classes during the time to implement the animation. Another alternative might be using something like [Pose](https://popmotion.io/pose/).

Comment: @HashemQolami I didn't get what you mean by `playing with its html classes`. Would you please give me more details of it?

Comment: @MostafaGhadimi In short, I meant adding or removing the classes. Say `.sidebar-in` and `sidebar-out` are responsible for the animation. At some points (e.g. when the visibility state changes), you should add/remove the classes from the `<Sidebar />` to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem were in the place that I have added an eventListener to whole document!

I have changed the style of coding approach (as [@AjayGupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8349557/ajay-gupta) said) to the following:

> **Solution of first problem:** It was fixed by reading the trick [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174353/addeventlistener-to-all-but-one-element). To explain it briefly, I have added an ignore variable that whenever the user clicks on the sidebar Component, the function returns and doesn't do anything else.

`Sidebar.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Icon} from 'antd';

import Sidebar from '../sidebar/sidebar.js';
import '../../css/navbar.css';

class Navbar extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sidebarVisible: false
        }
        this.sidebarShow = this.sidebarShow.bind(this);
        this.sidebarHide = this.sidebarHide.bind(this);
    }

    sidebarShow(){

        this.setState({
            sidebarVisible: true
        })
        document.querySelector('.sidebar').className = "sidebar sidebar-in"
        document.querySelector('.sidebar').style.display = "block"
        document.addEventListener('click', this.sidebarHide);

    }

    sidebarHide(e){
        // TODO: implement sidebar in a different way

        this.setState({
            sidebarVisible: false
        })

        var ignore = document.querySelector('.sidebar')
        var target = e.target
        if (target === ignore || ignore.contains(target)) {
            return
        }
        document.querySelector('.sidebar').className = "sidebar sidebar-out"
        setTimeout(
            () => document.querySelector('.sidebar').style.display = 'none'
        , 800)
        document.removeEventListener('click', this.sidebarHide)
    }

    render (){
        return (
            <div className="nav-container">

                <div className="bar" onClick={() => this.sidebarShow()} >
                    <Icon type="bars"/>
                </div>

                <div className="nav-logo">
                    خفت کتاب
                </div>

                <Sidebar/>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Navbar
```

> Solution of second problem: I have added two classes (`sidebar-in` and `sidebar-out` and add them to the `sidebar` class in appropriated situations:

`sidebar.css`:

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #001529;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: white;
    display: none;
}

.sidebar-in {
    animation-name: 'sidebar-in';
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}

.sidebar-out {
    animation-name: 'sidebar-out';
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}

@keyframes sidebar-in {
    from {transform: translateX(250px);}
    to {transform: translateX(0);}
}

@keyframes sidebar-out {
    from {transform: translateX(0);}
    to {transform: translateX(250px);}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add animation, you can create a css class for the sidebar component `.is-visible` and instead of doing:

`{this.state.sidebarVisible ? <Sidebar/> : null}`

you can do this:

`<Sidebar isVisible={this.state.sidebarVisible} />`

Now depending on the value of the `isVisible` prop value, add or remove the `is-visible` class from the sidebar component's container i.e. `<div className="sidebar">`

You can do it like this

```
.sidebar {
  ...,
  width: 320px;
  transition: transform 0.2s linear;
  transform: translateX(-320px); // assuming the sidebar is on the left side
}

.sidebar.is-visible {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Would you please check the post again? I have just added the `sidebar.css`.

Comment: Oh okay, but as I said, instead of doing `{this.state.sidebarVisible ? <Sidebar/> : null}`, do this `<Sidebar isVisible={this.state.sidebarVisible} />` and depending on the prop value, add or remove the `visible` class

Comment: I have tried, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me!
please give me more detail to solve the problem if I made a mistake in your solution.
thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
import '../../css/sidebar.css'

class Sidebar extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
        <div className="sidebar" onClick={event => event.stopPropagation()}>
            <div className="sidebar-user">
                <div className="sidebar-profile">
                    <img src={require('../../images/personal.jpg')}/>
                </div>
                <div className="sidebar-welcome">
                    مصطفی قدیمی
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="sidebar-active sidebar-elements">
                <div className="sidebar-icon">
                    <Icon type="home" />
                </div>
                <div className="sidebar-title">
                    خانه
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="sidebar-elements">
                <div className="sidebar-icon">
                    <Icon type="book" />
                </div>
                <div className="sidebar-title">
                    ثبت کتاب
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="sidebar-elements">
                <div className="sidebar-icon">
                    <Icon type="info-circle" />
                </div>
                <div className="sidebar-title">
                    درباره ما
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="sidebar-elements">
                <div className="sidebar-icon">
                    <Icon type="mail" />
                </div>
                <div className="sidebar-title">
                    تماس با ما
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

}

export default Sidebar;

Comment: I've added the event function that you said, but it still doesn't work properly!

Comment: Make sure you add some explanation of what you changed and fixed, so that the OP can better understand the solution.